# using sejda-console to create a file refering to the wildcard as a variable

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to use sejda-console.bat to split a pdf by bookmarks

My command looks like this and works fine;

`sejda-console.bat splitbybookmarks -l 2 -f c:\input\*.pdf -o c:\output\ -p [BOOKMARK_NAME]`

What I was hoping to do was to take the filename of the input file and use that as the output subdirectory. ie:

> c:\input\xyz.pdf --> c:\output\xyz\bookmarkname.pdf

Probably just a for loop, but I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the for loop working...

`for %%f in (c:\input\*.pdf) do (
   if not exist C:%%~Nf md C:%%~Nf
   C:\sejda-console-1.0.0.M9\bin\sejda-console.bat splitbybookmarks -l 2 -f %%f -o C:%%~Nf\ -p [BOOKMARK_NAME]`
)